# Get stack trace for IIS 7.5 and C# for every exception

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5, stack-trace

I have a C# WCF application running on IIS 7.5.

If an exception is thrown I get the generic request failed page. In order to find the guilty code, I'd like to get a full stack trace including line numbers and file names. How can I do that?

Whether the stack is returned directly or logged internaly on the server doesn't matter, as long I can see what is causing the error.

**Update**: Thanks for the answers so far. Unfortunately I'm a IIS/c# newbee. Are there any tutorials or step by step instructions? I've just no clue what to do with the answers so far.

Comment: Have you looked at elmah http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Answer (score 1):

you could use a couple of event handlers in your code to call some logging function

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

and

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

also, you should set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults=true` in your service behaviour configuration

Comment: Sorry I'm rather new to C# and IIS. I've no idea where to put this things. Could you give me some more information?

Comment: the first two examples should be called very early on in your application lifecycle, you will also need to write the functions that will actually log the errors, details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx, the third example should go in the `ServiceBehaviour` section of your `web.config` file

Answer (score 1):

you can provide more information With `FaultExceptions`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx

some examples:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/wcf-error-handling-and-faultexceptions/

Answer (score 0):

- Put calls in Try-Catch statements to log the error. The [ASP.Net Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) function is perfect for this task.
- Or bubble up the exception to a logging function passing in and logging the `Exception.StackTrace`.
- Do it in one foul swoop using the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` @paul mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I added a program I called ExceptionTrace to the http://stackdump.codeplex.com/ project in version 4. 1 Beta that will trace all generated exceptions without any changes in the code. It only attach itself as a debugger and listen to all generated exceptions.